# messy UITableViewCell with expand/collapse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement the expand/collapse table view cell as explained [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/). The modification that I have is that I want this to be a full expand/collapse table view. So each section can be collapsed/expanded. I looked at Apple's example and it seems to be an overkill.

The issue I am facing currently is mainly due to the formatting and color issues. The functionality seems to be fine. I wanted the section header to have a white background and the rows to have a blue background. Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (dimension.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
       if (!indexPath.row)
          {
              cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18];
              cell.textLabel.text = [timeslot objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
              if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
              {
                  cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
              }
              else
              {
                  cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
              }
          }
          else
          {
              // all other rows
              cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
              cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
              cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
              cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
              NSArray *listItems = [[timeslot objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
              if (indexPath.row == 1){
                  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:00 - %@:15", [listItems objectAtIndex:0], [listItems objectAtIndex:0]];
              }
              if (indexPath.row == 2){
                 cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:15 - %@:30", [listItems objectAtIndex:0], [listItems objectAtIndex:0]];
              }
              if (indexPath.row == 3){
                 cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:30 - %@:45", [listItems objectAtIndex:0], [listItems objectAtIndex:0]];
              }
              if (indexPath.row == 4){
                  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:45 - %d:00", [listItems objectAtIndex:0], ([[listItems objectAtIndex:0] intValue] + 1)];
              }

            }

        }


    if (dimension.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        Discount * discount = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = discount.vendor; 
    }

    return cell;
}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/route.json" objectClass:[Location class] delegate: self];

    RouteMapViewController * routemap = [[RouteMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RouteMapViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton =    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                      style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                      // style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                      // style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                     target:nil
                                                                     action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];

    if (dimension.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
            if (!indexPath.row)
            {
                // only first row toggles expand/collapse
                [preference deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

                NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
                BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
                NSInteger rows;

                NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

                if (currentlyExpanded)
                {
                    rows = [self tableView:preference numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                    [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

                }
                else
                {
                    [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                    rows = [self tableView:preference numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                }


                for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
                {
                    NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i 
                                                                   inSection:section];
                    [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
                }

                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                if (currentlyExpanded)
                {
                    [preference deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                    cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

                }
                else
                {
                    [preference insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                    cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];

                }
            }

     }
```

Here's what I expect it to look like (the font of the section is wrong as I've set it to Arial Bold, but it's not here)

[image]

Here's what I get when expanding the bottom section:

[image]

This mess started to happen after I scroll the UITableView to expand a later entry... I guess it has to do with updating the view..

Comment: we are unable to see images? are you using viewForSection method?

Comment: no.. there is no viewForSection method. What images are you referring to?

Comment: As I am not able to see images could you please tell what weird thing is happening?

Comment: I wanted the section to have white background and the rows to not have a disclosure button.. I set that in code.. however as you can see the rows have disclosure button

Comment: I edited the image and question above, I hope it's a bit clear

Comment: no its just showing "enter image description here" nothing else.

Comment: not sure if it's the problem with your browser... I tried with three browsers across 2 computers and it's fine

Comment: did you try using a different browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **cell reuse problem**. You need to reset / set each and every cell property each time, when you're reusing table cells.

For example cell.accessoryView is whatever it happened to be previous time that cell was last time used. Try setting it as nil.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    // Creating NEW cell
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Now you are using either NEW or OLD cell
// You MUST set each cell property that can be different

// code to customize cell for certain purpose

return cell;
```

}

Depending on section and row, you seem to be setting cell.textLabel.font, cell.textLabel.text, cell.accessoryView, cell.contentView.backgroundColor, cel.textLabel.backgroundColor etc.

Cell reuse means that **sometimes you get an old cell AS IT WAS USED last time**. Therefore you need to set all those values, which you have set before. If some values are always same, then define those only once when you create a branch new cell.

Yes, it's a lot of work. You could change all those long if clauses to switch cases, start using predefined arrays accessed via indexes and maybe Interface Builder XIBs for different cells. You can also use several different cellIdentifiers for different kind of cells, if you wish. In that case reuse is less problem, but it's easier to make mistakes...

Comment: hmmm...where do I reset that?

Answer (score 0):

To make changes in rows appearance, you should change them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. make suitable changes in that method.

for changing header for tableView you can use following code...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


        UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        [tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 44)];
        [tempLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [tempLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [tempLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
        [tempLabel setText:[sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section]];
        [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];
        [tempLabel release];
        return [tempView autorelease];

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: this doesn't work... I hope you look at the code and see why this doesn't work.. it's an expanding/collapsed row